# Как сделать полную копию удаленного репозитория в локальный?

Tags: git

1. Я клонировал удаленный репозиторий
2. Локально я создал ветку, и сделал в ней работу
3. Я запушил все свои изменения на удаленный репозиторий
4. На сайте репозитория я нажал кнопку "пул реквест"
5. Хозяину репозитория понравилась моя работа и он нажал "замерджить ветку этого парня, в нашу главную ветку", а так же поставил галочку "после мерджа удалить, более не нужную ветку этого парня"
6. Это всё длилось 3 дня и много людей работало над репозиторием
7. Какую мне теперь команду ввести чтобы git:

- Выкачал мне на ло калку все новосозданные за все это время другими людьми ветки
- Обновил на моей локалке обновленные другими людьми ветки
- Удалил у меня с локалки ветки которых не существует на удаленке

8. Я хочу не вводить имя своей ветки я хочу о нем не думать и его забыть, я хочу чтобы git просто сделал такое же поведение как "git clone" с полным синхроном лолкалки и ремоута.

Я хочу определить ПОСТАВИЛ ЛИ он ту галку "удалить ветку после мерджа" или не поставил, по признаку того "будет ли она у меня локкально на компе присутствовать или исчезнет", не пиша и не спрашивая его в мессенджере "поставил ли ты галку?" =)

Подскажите как я могу это сделать не удаляя папку .git и не делая git clone?

Comment: Возможно, поможет: https://gist.github.com/piaoger/8b10e42b382d58f418d9. `git clone`, кстати, копирует не полностью весь удалённый репозиторий к Вам, а только одну ветку (обычно `master`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Выкачал мне на ло калку все новосозданные за все это время другими людьми ветки

```
git fetch
```

все выкачает

> Обновил на моей локалке обновленные другими людьми ветки

```
git pull
```

выполнит предыдущую команду, плюс сделает merge (или rebase) с локальными ветками того, что было скачано

> Удалил у меня с локалки ветки которых не существует на удаленке

```
git pull --prune
```

А эта команда ещё и подчистит те ветки, которые были удалены. Похоже это то, что Вам хочется.

> Я хочу не вводить имя своей ветки я хочу о нем не думать и его забыть, я хочу чтобы git просто сделал такое же поведение как "git clone" с полным синхроном лолкалки и ремоута.

а для этого ещё нужно время от времени делать

```
git gc
```

но лучше это делать аккуратно.

Comment: вау =) а я думал "git pull --prune" это пишется типа как "git pull --forced" и не мог найти в докках) спасибо большое добрый человек =)

Comment: prune просто заставляет сверить привязанные ветки и подчистить их, если в origin их удалили

Comment: `git gc` запускается время от времени самим `git` во время, например, `git remote update -p` (что я рекомендую вместо `git pull --prune`).

Comment: да, я знаю, что git gc запускается время от времени.